# How to generate openssl certificate with expiry less than one day?

Tags: linux, openssl

I am trying to create CA signed End Entity certificate using openssl commands as shown below, in Linux:

```
# openssl genrsa -des3 -out clientkey.pem 2048
# openssl req -new -key clientkey.pem -out clientcert.csr
# cp clientkey.pem clientkey.pem.org
# openssl rsa -in clientkey.pem.org -out clientkey.pem
# openssl x509 -req -days 1 -in clientcert.csr -out clientcert.pem -CA cacert.pem -CAkey cakey.pem -CAcreateserial
```

Is it possible to specify the expiry time in hours, instead of days? I need to generate certificates with, say 1 hour expiry time, for some testing.

Openssl command seems to support some options to specify startdate and enddate, but I am not able to figure out how to use that. ( I am assuming enddate might support specifying date, and time).

```
#openssl x509 -req -startdate 120814050000Z -enddate 120814060000Z -in clientcert.csr -out clientcert.pem -CA cacert.pem -CAkey cakey.pem -CAcreateserial

unknown option 120814050000Z
usage: x509 args
.
.
-startdate      - notBefore field
-enddate        - notAfter field
.
.
-days arg       - How long till expiry of a signed certificate - def 30 days
```

Comment: Did the answer given solve your problem or not? If yes, you should try to mark this question as "answered".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or here is another way that I have found to work

Say I want my certificate to expire in 10 mins as a test

> The current date is feb 17th 
> The current time is 4:40pm
>
> First I set my system date to -1 day: Feb 16th 
> I set my system clock to +10 mins: 4:50pm

I create my cert using `openssl x509` to expire in 1 day which really means expire on today `Feb 17th`

```
openssl x509 -req -days 1 -in clientcert.csr -signkey cert.key -out ssl.crt
```

I then reset my system clock and time to the actual date and time and voila you have a certificate that is going to expire in 10 mins!

Obviously not the real way to do things but nice and easy for creating self signed certificates for dev use.

Comment: Moving the clock is an awful practice. Think your script runs on server - moving the time will screw things up.

Comment: An alternative to adjusting time for an application is using faketime as described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359225/create-self-signed-certificate-with-end-date-in-the-past maybe?

Comment: This is awful practice, but if you need to generate a few one-off expired certs it's also about 1000 times easier than the "proper" answer given below.

Comment: There is a time and place where this is actually appropriate. The answer provided should include clarification that this should never be included in any sort of script that is run in a CI/CD or other process. Changing the datetime on your local system would be done manually, and then changed back (or synced w a time server on whatever schedule you have setup). I have a scenario where I need an expired, self-signed cert to pass my unit tests. This approach means I can finish today, instead of setting expiry for 1 day out and then waiting 2 days to test.

Comment: I like this approach, except I make a new VM, change the clock inside the VM, issue my cert from within the VM, then I destroy the VM.  Other times I would consider using `faketime` as alternative.

Answer (score 45):

The -startdate and -enddate options for the x509 command are display options. You can set specific start and end time using the ca command instead to sign the certificate.

Try something like this:

```
openssl ca -config /etc/openssl.cnf -policy policy_anything -out clientcert.pem -startdate 120815080000Z -enddate 120815090000Z -cert ca.pem -keyfile cakey.pem -infiles clientcert.csr
```

Comment: I was able to set the start and end dates to values in the past and that worked as well.

Comment: I can't find any way to make this command work without needing a huge, properly constructed openssl.cnf file. This seems ridiculous because if I didn't need to override the dates I could use the trivial x509 command instead. Is there any way to make this work without the config?

Comment: That should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 21):

**Step-1.** Install faketime

```
sudo apt-get install faketime
```

**Step-2.** Generate expired certificate a day before currentdate.

```
faketime 'last friday 5 pm' /bin/bash -c 'openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 6 -nodes'
```

**Step-3** Verify the certificate validity date

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.pem
Certificate
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 10001009279078968790 (0x8acab8f3a2e32dd6)
    Signature Algoritm: sha256WithRsaEncryption
        Issuer: C=AU, ST=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
        Validity:
            Not Before: May 15 17:00:03 2020 GMT
            Not After : May 21 17:00:03 2020 GMT
        Subject: C=AU, ST=Some-State, Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
...
```

Comment: Please don't provide information as image if it can be text

Comment: Fantastic. I could able to create an expired certificate for my testing! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try [gossl](https://securitykiss.com/resources/tutorials/gossl_project/) that allows specifying cert validity start date and duration in various time units.

I developed it to overcome limitations of command line openssl. 
The tool is lightweight, implemented in Go, without dependencies, under MIT license.

Comment: That link no longer takes me to the package. Is this the same software? https://github.com/yakuter/gossl

Answer (score 0):

using faketime is a good way

1. install faketime

   sudo apt-get install faketime
2. generate client certificate by faketime command ( example 2.4h = 0.1day)

   faketime -f '-0.9d' openssl ca -in client.req -out client.crt -extfile x509-types/client -days 1 -batch -config ./openssl.cnf

-0.9d day mean:
if current time is 2024.02.25 12:00.
The openssl command is simulated running at the time : 2024.02.24 14:24
(the duration of certificate is 1 day)

Then the output certificate will expired in next 2.4h (2024.02.25 14:24)

Answer (score -5):

You can set the `-days` option to 0:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 0 -in clientcert.csr -signkey cert.key -out ssl.crt
```

That will create a certificate with a `notBefore` and `notAfter` equal to the current time (i.e. you certificate will expire immediately).

Comment: This does not work, when attempting this I got an error saying `req: Non-positive number "0" for -days`